# Angular2 modal call method in parent from the child

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal

Need to utilize modals using [ngx-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals). Tried by calling modal from parent component, do task within the modal, click save, then give that data back to parent to run a method based on result.

Parent component calls the `modalService` and loads a component into it.

`this._bsModalRef = this._modalService.show(ConfirmActiveModalComponent);`

Component loaded has a single method in it: `save()`.

**Parent Component:**

```
import { ConfirmActiveModalComponent } ....

openModal(){
    this._bsModalRef = this._modalService.show(ConfirmActiveModalComponent);
}

addNewRecord(){
    // I need this to run when the modal "Save" button is clicked
}
```

**Modal Component:**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-confirm-existing-version-modal',
    templateUrl: './confirmExistingVersionModal.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./confirmExistingVersionModal.component.css']
})

export class ConfirmExistingVersionModalComponent {

    constructor(
        public _bsModalRef: BsModalRef,
    ) { }

    save() {
       // Some data here from the modal
    }

}
```

**Modal Component HTML:**

```
<div>
    <div class="modal-header text-center">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        xx
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="_bsModalRef.hide()">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="save()">Save</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**How to run the `addNewRecord()` method in parent when clicking on save button in modal?**

I didn't see any callbacks or promises returned from `bsModalRef`, so don't know where to start. Do I create a subscription in parent for each modal called, to be able to listen for data emitted by modal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create `EventEmitter` or `Subject` property in your modal component to emit some data from child component:

**Modal Component:**

```typescript
export class ConfirmExistingVersionModalComponent {
  saved: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  ... 
  save() {
    this.saved.emit('someData');
  }
}
```

And then all you need to do is subscribe to this event in your parent component:

**Parent Component:**

```typescript
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';
...

openModal(){
  this._bsModalRef = this._modalService.show(ConfirmExistingVersionModalComponent );
  this._bsModalRef.content.saved.take(1).subscribe(this.addNewRecord.bind(this))
}

addNewRecord(someData){
  alert(`Save button has been clicked. Data received: ${someData}`);
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/XbJQMbSwpmDtEQnB1ehU?p=preview)**

Comment: amazing.. I have spent a good few hours trying to come up with a solution for this. Is this a pretty common approach or would it be more ideal for the modal library to offer some type of callback / promise?

Comment: It's common approach for components that are created dynamically